# New url format in Django 1.9

Tags: django, django-urls, django-1.9

I recently upgraded my Django project to version 1.9.

When I try to run `migrate`, I am getting the following two errors:

1. `Support for string view arguments to url() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 (got app.views.about). Pass the callable instead.`
2. `django.conf.urls.patterns() is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10. Update your urlpatterns to be a list of django.conf.urls.url() instances instead.`

Could someone please show me the proper syntax of how to do this? A brief sample of my `urls.py` is below:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^about/$', 'app.views.about',
        name='about'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('accounts.views',
    url(r'^signin/$', 'auth_login',
        name='login'),
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Here is the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urls/#url)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Import your views directly, or your views modules:

```
from apps.views import about
from accounts import views as account_views
```

Do not use `patterns` at all, just use a list or tuple:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^about/$', about,
        name='about'),
]

urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^signin/$', account_views.auth_login,
        name='login'),
]
```

Answer (score 4):

You should remove the quotes around views name.
So your code will be like that

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^about/$', app.views.about, #without quote!
        name='about'),
)
```

Point 2, use lists, so your code will transform to

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^about/$', app.views.about, #without quote!
            name='about'),
    ]
```